# table access security - ms sql server azure

Tags: sql-server

I read somewhere that "table access level security" does not exist for sql server azure. Unfortunately, I cannot find the blog/page anymore. Can experts please clarify this, ideally with some evidence? Thanks.

Comment: if you down vote at least say why. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have heard it wrong probably; It's allowed. Per [MSDN Documentation On: SQL Server Feature Limitations (Azure SQL Database)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394115.aspx)

The limitation list doesn't include `table level permission security`.

Again, per MSDN  [Documentation On: GRANT Object Permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188371.aspx) it says

> Applies to: SQL Server (SQL Server 2008 through current version),
>   **Azure SQL Database**.

Which apparently implies that, you can grant table level access permission in SQL Azure as well.

Comment: Apparently, so is it actually the case? (-:

Comment: That's what I see from document. If not, then specification is wrong .. not my fault.